# Error in write.lock in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

By Hibernate search we create a search engine in my application. Here same application running in two different **JBoss** and using two different folder for storing index data. Two folder and Two **JBoss** running in different system. But some time showing bellow type of error. Please, give me any resolution.

> 16:45:58,184 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler] (Hibernate
>   Search: Index updates queue processor for index
>   in.issac.wisebank.systemadmin.customermanagement.entiry.WbSaCustomermaster-1)
>   HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred
>   org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed
>   out: NativeFSLock@/Folder_Path/write.lock Primary Failure: Entity
>   in.issac.wisebank.systemadmin.customermanagement.entiry.WbSaCustomermaster
>   Id 49621 Work Type org.hibernate.search.backend.UpdateLuceneWork :
>   org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed
>   out:
>   NativeFSLock@/home/ccblcbs/wisebankenterprise/globalsearch/index12/in.issac.wisebank.systemadmin.customermanagement.entiry.WbSaCustomermaster/write.lock
>   at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
>   [lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40] at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:1098)
>   [lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2 1423725 - rmuir - 2012-12-18 19:45:40] at
>   org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:146)
>   [hibernate-search-engine-4.4.4.Final.jar:4.4.4.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:113)
>   [hibernate-search-engine-4.4.4.Final.jar:4.4.4.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:117)
>   [hibernate-search-engine-4.4.4.Final.jar:4.4.4.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:101)
>   [hibernate-search-engine-4.4.4.Final.jar:4.4.4.Final] at
>   org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:67)
>   [hibernate-search-engine-4.4.4.Final.jar:4.4.4.Final] at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_24] 16:45:58,187 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask]
>   (Hibernate Search: Index updates queue processor for index
>   in.issac.wisebank.systemadmin.customermanagement.entiry.WbSaCustomermaster-1)
>   HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous
>   error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by Windows, you should read about LOCKING STRATEGY.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html_single/#search-configuration-directory-lockfactories

Comment: I realise I am extremely late to the party, but I'm experiencing this issue 3.5 years later. Could you please elaborate on how this is caused by Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This version of Hibernate Search is extremely old; this issue could occasionally happen but was resolved. You need to update.